# How can I install python-gasp on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gasp

I use a Ubuntu 16.04 system, and I want to install the `gasp` for python.
I was told that the following commands can help me to install the `python-gasp`:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install python-gasp
```

I tried the commands, but it seems not to work, because when I run

```
from gasp import
```

it returned as

```
"No module named gasp".
```

Then I use `$ whereis python-gasp` to check the location of the `python-gasp` I installed, and it returned as `/usr/share/python-gasp`

I don't know what happened.
How can I use `gasp` successfully?

Comment: did you get error message when you use apt-get ? Do you use Python2 ? Ubuntu16 as default use Python3. `python-gasp` is for Python2, `python3-gasp` can be for Python3 . If `whereis` can find it then maybe it is program which you can run `$ python-gasp`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed the default into python2.7 when I finished the Ubuntu16 installing. And I use' $python --version' to confirm this, it says 'Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)'. So, I can make sure that the default mode is Python2.

Comment: don't change default Python in Ubuntu because it uses Python for many things - it can crush system. You can have both version installed and use `python2` or `python2.7` and `pip2`, `pip2.7` (and `python3`, `pip3`)

Comment: I checke `gasp` in internet. It is almost 5 years old, there is no version for Python3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggest, I am a novice on Linux and Python. But I love them deeply. I will work hard to learn bash, linux and python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-gasp` is module for Python 2. I don't see `python3-gasp` for Python 3 (Linux Mint 17 based on Ubuntu 14.04) but maybe you have on Ubuntu 16.

Ubuntu 16 as default use Python 3. Maybe you will have to install Python 2 to use `gasp`.

Or maybe you already have installed. Try `python2` or `which python2` to find path.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed the default into python2.7 when I finished the Ubuntu16 installing. And I use' $python --version' to confirm this, it says 'Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)'. So, I can make sure that the default mode is Python2.    And I found a error when I was installing GASP, it said:"Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)".